# 'trim' of undefined TypeError in Angular app when I don't call trim anywhere

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to learn Angular and as I'm working through a couple of ideas I had, I ran into the following error in the dev console of Chrome:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at Function.addMultipleClasses (primeng-dom.js:19)
    at ButtonDirective.createIconEl (primeng-button.js:59)
    at ButtonDirective.setIconClass (primeng-button.js:78)
    at ButtonDirective.set label [as label] (primeng-button.js:92)
    at setInputsForProperty (core.js:10940)
    at elementPropertyInternal (core.js:9984)
    at ɵɵpropertyInterpolate1 (core.js:15551)
    at Module.ɵɵpropertyInterpolate (core.js:15514)
    at CmsComponent_Template (cms.component.html:12)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9579)
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<h1>Angular Router App</h1>
<!-- This nav gives you links to click, which tells the router which route to use (defined in the routes constant in  AppRoutingModule) -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">/login</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">/</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<button type="button"
        pButton
        label="{{word}}"
        (click)="buttonPress()">
</button>
<!-- The routed views render in the <router-outlet>-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And here is my TS:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './cms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cms.component.scss']
})
export class CmsComponent implements OnInit {
  private onWord: number = 0;
  private words: Array<string> = ["One","Two","Three","Two"];
  public word: string = this.words[this.onWord];

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public buttonPress(): void {
    // Bumps the index
    this.onWord++;
    // Keeps the value in the proper range
    if (this.onWord >= this.words.length) {
      this.onWord = 0;
    }
    // Updates the word to the new index
    this.word = this.words[this.onWord];
    console.log("The button is now on " + this.word);
  }
}
```

I'm using Angular and Typescript. Any thoughts on what's going wrong? The button functions as intended except for that error whenever I click it.

Thanks!

Comment: Follow the trace of the error. The error resulted from `primeng-dom.js:19`

Comment: Try removing that pButton Directive?from the console i hope it's something around that pButton

Comment: Fixed in Primeng 12.2.1: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out having `{{word}}` as the button label broke things!

Apparently I can't have dynamically changing button labels...

Answer (score 3):

was the same problem, I found a solution on the official forum, in order to fix the error you need to add -> icon = "pi"

```
   <button
        icon="pi"
        type="button"
        pButton
        [label]="(documentsCount$ | async)?.toString()"
    ></button>
```

Comment: The forum entry is this one: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=67536

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error generated from your code but in the package you're using (in this case PrimeNg). The method seems to be expecting some input which it's not getting. Try passing '$event' in the click method and handle it in the ts file.

```
(click)="buttonPress($event)"
```

As an ideal implementation, use the predefined button element provided by PrimeNg.

Answer (score 0):

Use `p-button` instead:

```
<p-button
        label="{{word}}"
        (onClick)="buttonPress()">
</p-button>
```

See the [forum entry](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=194460&sid=c49316d263f4fc8cef8e0d9fe936695d#p194460)